# SimpleXML Xpath() Name() returning False

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml, return-value

I'm working on a server with PHP 5.0.5, so I can't get XML tag names with getName(). **Instead, I'm trying to use the name() function in the xpath() method with SimpleXML.**

I'm attempting to get the name of the tag just below the root node, but I can't even get the name of the root node, as seen below.

```
<?php
$xml_file = simplexml_load_file(data.xml);
if ($xml_file) {
    var_dump($xml_file->xpath("name(/*)"));
}
?>
```

**This prints 'bool(false)'. What would cause the name() function in Xpath to return false?**

The below also correctly returns an array of all the elements in the file, so the file should be valid.

```
var_dump($xml_file->xpath("/*"));
```

Comment: You need to update PHP to a recent version

Comment: If it was possible I wouldn't have posted the question, and I assume it's unrelated to why the function returns false anyway.

Comment: Why can't you update PHP?

Comment: In the past when they tried to upgrade it apparently broke many of the pages - I'm low on the chain and can't push them to work on fixing that. There must be some way to get tag names in SimpleXML before getName() was implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically your `XPath` query is wrong. I would use the DOM extension like this:

```
$xml = <<<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

$result = $selector->query('//*');
foreach($result as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeName . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
note
to
from
heading
body
```

---

There is also a way to achieve it without the `getName()` function, because the tag names are the member names in an `SimpleXmlElement` object. You need to write a recursive parser, (I've replaced recursion by iteration to improve the performance):

```
$xml = <<<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
  <address>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani<a>dsf</a></from>
  </address>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
EOF;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$stack = array($xml);
do {
    $el = array_pop($stack);
    foreach($el as $key => $val) {
        if(gettype($val) !== 'string') {
            $stack []= $val;
        }
        echo $key . PHP_EOL;
    }
} while (!empty($stack));
```

Btw, PHP `5.0.5` is pretty old. Unbelievable that you/they are still using it. **update!** However, the code above should work with that version of PHP.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think they're updating soon, but not soon enough. I'll try this. Would be nice to know why the xpath() is wrong though.

Comment: `name(//*)` will not give you a list of node names, in no xpath version. if you use `$selector->evaluate('name(//*)');` you'll get the name of the *first* returned node, in my example `note`. Please note that you'll need to use `evaluate()` instead of `query()` when using the `DOM` extension and you want the result of a function execution to be returned. I don't know how simplexml handles this actually, but you see that the xpath `name()` will not work like you expect, regardless of the API being used to execute queries.